# "No more sound" or "no sounder"? Or are both valid?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing an essay for an English subject about the film *The Shawshank Redemption*.

I've used the sentence

> But though the Warden presides over many prisoners, he is morally **no sounder** and stands less chance of reform.

My teacher has corrected **no sounder** to **no more sound**, but Microsoft Word identifies the latter phrase as grammatically faulty. **No more sound** does sound odd when isolated, but I can't put my finger on *why* specifically.

There are mixed opinions online, to the point that citing them here would do little good.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I was so tempted to make the question _Or are both equally **sound**?_

Comment: 'Sounder' is an unusual word, and may be other than the comparative adjective. Even a group of wild pigs. For once, I think the choice of a periphrastic comparative for a monosyllabic adjective is quite justified (though it would be pedantic to label either choice incorrect).

Comment: Off Topic, but what about rephrasing? "..he is [just] as immoral, and stands less chance..."

Comment: I think you could have a general rule here that if the adjective in question (sound) **also has a verb form with a totally different meaning** (which sound does), then you should avoid this construction, as some people will read it as "verb-er" - someone who makes a sound, in this case.

Comment: _But though_ is a bit weird too. However, there is justification for it [in Shakespeare](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/twelfthnight/page_62.html).

Comment: Interesting. Could _no more sound_ also be interpreted as _not sound anymore_, though? @MaxWilliams

Comment: I could see the sentence being rephrased as _he is at least as immoral as them_, but this is clunkier. @Bluewoman

Comment: You dislike my earlier suggestion? If you preferred, you could rephrase it  *... prisoners, like them, he is **morally unsound** and stands less chance ...*

Comment: Ah, I forgot to explain. I want to convey the thought _at least as immoral, if not worse_ rather than _just as immoral_. Partly for dramatic emphasis, partly because I believe it to the be the case. @Bluewoman

Comment: Oh, I see. "... he is as immoral, if not more so..." reveals that the Warden is   even more immoral / corrupt than the inmates. Sometimes it is worth spending a few extra words to convey one's meaning precisely.

Comment: "no more sound" **could** be interpreted as "not sound anymore" but would more likely be interpreted as the **noun** form, like "no more noise".  If you wanted to say "not sound anymore" you could say "sound no more", eg "He used to be sound but he is sound no more".  This is an unusual usage though.  Sound has many different meanings (noun, verb and adjectve) so there is a lot of potential for confusion.

Comment: No sounder and no more sound are both technically valid expressions of the sentiment on their own. I think the problem is in your sentence has nothing to do with that, but instead how it omits the noun that the adjectives should modify. "No more sound" is somewhat better in that regard, because sound is acting as an abstract noun in that case. However, I think a more accurate correction of the clause in question would be something along the lines of  "he is morally no sounder *than them*", or maybe "he is no sounder than them morally." although I couldn't tell you why I might move the adverb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The evidence below strongly suggests that ***sounder*** is a valid comparative form of the adjective, *sound*.

- “Unhappy being,” said the Abbot, “who hast no better subject of pleasantry than that which should make thee tremble — **no sounder** jest than thine own sins, and no better objects for laughter than those who can absolve thee from the guilt of ...
  Sir Walter Scott, [*The Abbot*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ES1NAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22no%20sounder%20jest%20than%20thine%20own%20sins%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLkdrR8OjOAhXFaxQKHX3LA34Q6AEITTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22no%20sounder%20jest%20than%20thine%20own%20sins%22&f=false), 1820
- We are willing that religion should be judged by its fruits ; there is **no sounder** principle than that ; but be sure to judge it by its fruits; do not judge it by anything else.
  *[The Nazarene](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bUwrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA260&dq=%22no%20sounder%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLiebu7-jOAhUDVxQKHXyMC3c4ChDoAQguMAI#v=onepage&q=%22no%20sounder%22&f=false)*, 1843
- This argument is obviously **no sounder** than the following: ‘How can language describe the world?’—‘Because the world is language-like—it is linguistic’, and **no sounder** than: 'How can the English language describe the world?—‘Because the world is intrinsically British.’
  Karl Popper, *Conjectures and Refutations: The Growth of Scientific Knowledge*, 1963
- There is **no sounder** investment than property. Land. You all know that a dollar won't buy what it used to buy. A dollar might not be worth but fifty cents a year from now.
  Cormac McCarthy, *[Child of God](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zea-uYKLTlEC&pg=PA7&dq=%22no%20sounder%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidtuKj8ujOAhUjDZoKHcm4Drc4KBDoAQg3MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22no%20sounder%22&f=false)*, 1973

And if we examine the noun phrase, **[sounder morals](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22sounder+morals%22&tbm=bks)**, Google Books yields over 240 instances of this usage.

- *but it is refreshing to see people young and old alike can have a hero in this day and age with a sound work ethic and even **sounder morals***.
- *Lincoln was not only more available than Seward, but he had **sounder morals** and better judgment than Seward, or any of the others. He was far better equipped ...*
- *The English romances have traditionally been said to embody **sounder morals**' because they drastically changed French concepts of love, sex and marriage and were 'less lascivious'*.
- *... under our Universities imparting Higher Education and training leaders, teachers, and professionals who would dedicate their services in the cause of better education, **sounder morals**, nobler manners, sweeter life and happier surroundings ...*

Comment: Excellent research.  All of those adjective examples could be written more clearly though, I think, as "No jest more sound than...", "No principle more sound than...", "is obviously no more sound than the following...", etc.  I **don't** think the noun phrase examples could be similarly rewritten.